# Graph with clickable nodes

Tags: org-mode

I maintain information about relationships between research papers in a `.org` file. I would like to visualize these relationships as a graph, where each node (vertex) of the graph corresponds to a paper and each arc signifies a relationship between two papers. I know that I can do this using `GraphViz DOT` as described [here](https://vxlabs.com/2014/12/04/inline-graphviz-dot-evaluation-for-graphs-using-emacs-org-mode-and-org-babel/). However, using that approach, the graph is just a picture. I would like this graph to have clickable nodes, whereby I would be able to open my notes about a paper (a `.org` file) by clicking on the node corresponding to that paper. Is there a tool I can use for creating such a graph with clickable nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The visualization technique you describe would be killer!  Some approaches come to mind:

**1. Render using text rather than SVG**

Plain text is very powerful- especially in Emacs.  Render your diagram to text using something like [Graph::Easy](http://www.bloodgate.com/perl/graph/manual/overview.html) Perl library (it accepts the graphviz dot format), insert that, and then do some "post-processing" in-buffer.  You can add text properties to stylize it or to add a keymap to make it clickable.  I'm not sure how effectively the layout may scale for large numbers of papers/nodes, but might be worth trying.  I would use placeholder text in the dot file to make post-processing easier.

**2. Use Emacs' XWidget support to render a webpage**

When compiled with [xwidgets](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsXWidgets), Emacs can render a usable web page in a window.  I have used this approach for a few personal projects and have found it to be very effective.  I would recommend building a single HTML document with the generalized JavaScript logic for rendering your style of chart (sort of a "canvas" document).  Once the page has loaded, provide the data via a JavaScript call (`xwidget-webkit-execute-script`).  Some [examples](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) using d3.js.  With the massive JavaScript ecosystem you can do all sorts of pretty things.

**3. Get creative with existing SVG capabilities**

A good demonstration of SVG functionality relevant for your purposes is [here](https://github.com/sabof/svg-thing).  It may not be feasible to work with an externally-generated SVG.

**4. Expand SVG functionality in Emacs to support links**

Since SVG supports [external links](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#Links), these could conceivably be used to represent your links to papers using URI's or URL's.  I suspect that [librsvg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/LibRsvg) (the library Emacs uses for rendering SVG's) doesn't support this sort of anchor link.